# Wordpress database not inserting values posted via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to retrieve a user's email and store it in the database using Ajax. I can see the form Values in the console after the ajax request,but it doesn't store the data in the database. Everything else works fine,except that nothing is stored in the Database.Any help with be much appreciated. You can test this using any default Wordpress TwentyFourteen installation. I am providing the following files. .subsc.js is the subscription script, the functions to send info is in the functions.php file and my subscription widget has been included. Copy and past

```
  class subscribeFm extends WP_Widget {

    /**
    * Register widget with Wordpress
    */

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct( 
            'subscribe_widget', // Base ID
            __( 'Newsletter Subscription', 'text_domain' ), // Name
            array( 'description' => __( 'Displays Subscription form', 'text_domain'), ) // args
        );

}
/* Front end Display of widget */
public function widget($args, $instance) {
    echo $args['before_widget'];
    if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
        echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] ). $args['after_title'];
   ?> 
<div>
    <form id="formsub" name="subscribe" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateSub(this)"> 
<input id="subEmail" name="subEmail" class="input-text" placeholder="Your Email Address">
<button type="submit">Signup</button>
<p id="notifEmail" style="color:#fff"></p>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
        </form>
</div>
<?php
    }

    // echo __('Subscribe to our mailing list', 'text_domain');
    echo $args['after_widget'];

}



public function form( $instance ) {

    $title =! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : __('New title', 'text_domain' );

?>

   <p> 
  <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"> <?php _e( 'Title'); ?></label>
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>" >
</p>

<?php
}

/** 
* Sanitize widget form values as they are saved
*
*/
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';

        return $instance;
    }
}


?>
```

Add this lines  to function twentyfourteen_scripts()   in functions.php

```
/* Email Subscription queue */


    wp_enqueue_script('subsc_Scripts',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/Subsc.js', array('jquery' ), 1.0,  true );

    wp_localize_script('subsc_Scripts', 'MySubsc', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
```

the following code processes the returned data in functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ph_process', 'ph_process_fm' ); // ajax for logged in users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ph_process', 'ph_process_fm' ); // ajax for not logged in users


// Process submission after Ajax request
function ph_process_fm($info) {
           global $wpdb;

if(isset($_POST['subEmail'])) {

   $subscripEmail = $_POST['subEmail'];


    echo $subscripEmail  . " </br>";

//   $nSubEmail = $wpdb->real_escape_string($subEmail);

   $wpdb->insert('wp_subscription_email', array('email' => $subscripEmail  ), array( '%s' ) );

}
die();

}
```

This is the Javascript Code

```
function validateSub() {

    //"use strict";
    var x, exp, result, atpos, dotpos, formData;
    formData = jQuery("#formsub").serialize();
    x = document.subscribe.subEmail.value;
    exp = /(\s|.$|.%)@(?=.)/gmi;
    atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
    result = exp.test(x);  // check Reg exp on input value

    if (result === true || (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2)) {

    document.getElementById("notifEmail").innerHTML = "Invalid Email address";   //display error messages
        document.getElementById("notifEmail").style.color="#FCFCFC";
        ERR = 1;
        return false;
    }

    else {
          jQuery.ajax({
              url: MySubsc.ajaxurl,
              type: 'POST',
              action: 'ph_process_fm',
              data: formData,
              success:function(response){

            alert("Check your email to confirm this subscription");
            alert(formData);
              }
                });

    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: provide your html and js link so we can check issue

Comment: I've provided the complete code.Pls take a look.thanks

Answer (score 0):

It will result success because the url is correct.

The error in your code is in here `action: 'ajaxurl',`

add `add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajaxurl', 'my_action_callback' );` to your `ajaxurl` and `function my_action_callback(){}`

Comment: I tried it, it didn't seem to work.No data was stored in the database

Comment: check in the `my_action_callback` function if `$_POST` or `$_GET` are working or better yet, use `$_REQUEST`. OR maybe `formData` has no value. There are bunch of debug options you can do like the url, empty variables,queries, etc. Also please check the documentation of ajax [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: Thanks .I tried the suggestions.the Ajax returns successfully but it's not calling action & I noticed that the $_POST data is not being retrieved by the my_callback-action in functions.php .it says undefined index 'email' . The input email is being sent from a form located in my widget-subscribe.php file using method='post'

Comment: try `$_REQUEST` not `$_POST`

Comment: i tried request, and got the same result.If you have the chance, please try the above code in wordpress TwentyFourteen theme, you can just copy and paste it.And test if it works for you.Thanks